# How to set a gap between 2 panels in c# winform, details below

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I place a panel with dock type left and place 2 panels with dock type top in the parent panel. But I want to place a gap between these 2 panels because the margin is not working on that panels. How to do that in C# winform? Please help...

Comment: Learn how to use Anchor; you'll probably never use Dock again!

Comment: just dock a third panel between them and set its borders and color so it looks like empty space, docking is your friend once you know how to use it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can when docking. What you could do is dock one `Panel` as container and then put another `Panel` inside that, leaving a margin as required and then anchoring to all four sides. The inner `Panel` is then used for your other controls rather than the outer.

Alternatively, you could use `Anchor` instead of `Dock`, which would allow you to explicitly position each `Panel`. The correct combination of anchored edges would simulate docking, i.e. top, left and bottom for the left `Panel` and top, left and right for the top `Panels`.

I guess the other alternative would be to introduce additional `Panels` to act specifically as separators between those you intend to use as containers.

Comment: Agree with all these, just wanted to add you can use a SplitPanel in left-right mode and in the right pane, put another SplitPanel in top-bottom mode that has another t-b SplitPanel in its bottom pane. You can fix the splitter position. Loads of ways to skin the cat; I personally would anchor

Comment: @CaiusJard, I hadn't considered as I've never actually used that control with a fixed splitter but it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help masters, but I got that. I place all the controls in a panel and set the parent panel bottom padding. With this, I got my desired layout.

Comment: @RajibGanguly, you seem to be saying that it wasn't about the `Panels` themselves but about the controls in the `Panels`. This is why it's important to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. be specific about the details of what you're trying to achieve and why and then we won't have to guess or assume, meaning that we can't guess or assume incorrectly.

Comment: @John, it is about panels and not controls on that panel. I am placing panels on a parent panel with dock type top for each child panel. But I want to set a gap between 2 dock type=top panels. I achieved that by placing the 2 child panels in a parent panel each and setting padding to 5 all and background of the parent panel is set to transparent. Voila, I got what I am trying to get. Thanks anyway masters.

Comment: @RajibGanguly, so exactly what I said in the first part of my answer. When you say "thanks but..." it rather implies that you didn't do as the solution suggests, but you did. Anyway, whatevs.